# Jquery Google Map Doesnt Display

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is a pretty simple one, but I cant get it to work, this is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/DYfbg/38/

```
// Map Display v0.1
//
// Future Improvements
// Only display if co-ordinates in URL

$(document).ready(function() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions)
}
```

I am trying to get it just to start with the "center" definition. Any ideas what is going on?
​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing ending ); at the end of your code. So it throws an error and never gets triggered.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nxtwrld/DYfbg/39/